# Problem with class Router in Cpanel - Cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cpanel, router

I have a problem with a class Router when install cakephp in Cpanel.

In any view i write: 
      $this->Html->link('Google','/users/add');
but show Google but the url is:
      http://{ip server}/cgi-sys/php4/users/add

I cant find the error.

The version of cakephp is 1.3.6 and I just downloaded it.

someone who can help me. Thanks.

Comment: and what url do you expect it to be?

Answer (score 1):

Check if the mod rewrite (php.ini) is enabled!